# force deleting a file in through bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have made a folder compiler for c using gcc and it creates useless files that I would like to delete when the program ends.
I run the folder compiler through a bat file but it won't let me delete the files at the end.
code:

```
compiler.exe
cls
runner.bat
del file.txt /F /Q
```

Comment: is the file used by another program?

Comment: no, it is initiated and closed.

Comment: Do you get any error message? Start a single command-line window and start you batch-file from there. This will prevent to fast closing and you can check whether it does not find the file, it is locked etc.

Comment: The bat file with only that line works fine, problem is that in the "complete" batch file it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are saying that the `delete` isn't taking place, then the reason is that

```
runner.bat
```

transfers execution to the batch `runner.bat` and when *that* terminates, so does the process.

You need

```
call runner.bat
```

which will return at the end of `runner.bat` and continue with your main batch.